# Add List Element Based on Conditional with Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects, linqpad

I have this very simple Linq query (the .Dump() function is being used with LinqPad in order to view the results):

```
void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<string>
    {
        "One", "Two", "Three"
    };


    var result = from o in myList
    select o;

    result.Dump();
}
```

How can I inject an if statement into the Linq query that populates `result` so that it checks to see if "Four" is in the list--and if it is not, then add it? I realize that there are ways to do this by looking at result after Linq has populated `result`, but I would like to add this logic into a single Linq query.

Thank you.

EDIT/CLARIFICATION: The "if" logic needs to be inside the Linq query. Here is the skeletal code:

```
 var result = from o in myList
    select o
    [now add "four" if and only if it is not in the result]
    [now end the query and ensure `result` contains "one", "two", "three", and "four"];
```

SECOND EDIT:
I am trying to query and add to the list in a single operation. By the way, I made this very simple example instead of giving the much more complex scenario I'm trying to handle, by the way, so it's not as if I am struggling with how to add a new element to a List object. :)

So here is what I was going to do:

// query the list to see if "four" is in the list
(a Linq query goes here to check for "four")

// if the result of the above is false then add "four" to the myArray List
(add the new array element here)

Instead, I would like to do the following:

// query the list for its contents and also add "four" if it is not in the list.
// all this needs to be done in a single "select" using Linq

Is this not possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think that the list will be queried twice? LINQ expressions are declarative not execution logic.

Comment: Revised after your comment. Actually, while making this easy example, I think I am creating confusion. My "more complex" real Linq issue would iterate through the list twice if it has nested selects. I don't want to go into that complexity in this question, however, so I revised my OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx) if you switch to method syntax:

```
var result = myList.Union(new [] {"Four"});
```

There's not really a clean way to to it using *just* query syntax. Query syntax only supports a small set of Linq operators, of which `union` is not one.

Comment: I'm not partial to the query syntax. What I want to see is the test of whether "four" is in the list, and if it isn't, add it. Is this done with a subselect in the Linq query? Where is your conditional test?

Comment: @Jazimov `Union` does that by definition.  It's the "union" set of the two collections, which by definition does not include items in both lists twice.

Comment: There's not an _if_ operator if that's what you're looking for. I suppose you could do `.Concat(new [] {"four"}).Where(s => !myList.Contains(s))` but that's effectively the same as `Union`.

Comment: `Union` will not query either list twice. It will keep track of what items have already bee found so it doesn't return the same element twice.

Comment: I think THAT is actually what I'm looking for! And now I see more about what your point is with Union. Please accept my apologies. Your Union solution probably is what I need! I will experiment and accept if that works.

Comment: Note that `Where(!Contains)` _will_ enumerate `myList` again, so if _that_ is your goal then `Where` is not the right answer.

Comment: Ah! Excellent point. Yes, I want to avoid querying the list twice. And, for the record, when I said I understood Union I clearly did not. Apologies. Thanks for the extra effort to set me straight.

Comment: Note: `Union` removes all duplicates, which has not been discussed.

Comment: Union removes all duplicates in the list or just removes items you're trying to add that might already be duplicated in the list? Interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a second list of items that you want to conditionally add, then combine the `Except` and `Concat` methods:

```
var myList = new List<string>
{
    "One", "Two", "Three"
};

var others = new List<string> {
    "Four"
};

var result = myList.Concat(others.Except(myList));

result.Dump();
```

Comment: Please see clarification in question. I need the conditional logic to be inside a single Linq construct. Thanks.

Comment: @Jazimov Do you mean that you want to use the query syntax? Or use only one method call?

Comment: I gave a skeletal example. I suppose I would answer that I want to use the query syntax vs one method call. Thanks.

Comment: I might have missed your .Except() above. If so, apologies. I think, however, that Union might be a more direct answer (see answer below this one). But thanks for illustrating .Except, it will be useful to me.

Comment: You could also flip it: `myList.Except(others).Concat(others)` but this wouldn't preserve the order of the original list.